# conjure-up openstack Exception in ev.run()

Tags: openstack, conjure-up

no matter what I try with conjure-up openstack
have done beta and also stable

It goes very well till last part where it suppose to give you horizon url and info, but it just exits. Is there any way to save this install? looks like it had finished but with a hiccups at the end! takes a long time to run .. 
16GB memory, AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor

```
$ conjure-up openstack Exception in ev.run(): Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ubuntui/ev.py", line 83, in run
    cls.loop.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 376, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1328, in run
    raise self._exc_info[0](self._exc_info[1]).with_traceback(self._exc_info[2]) TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'doc' and 'pos' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/conjure-up", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('conjure-up==2.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'conjure-up')()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/conjureup/app.py", line 321, in main
    EventLoop.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ubuntui/ev.py", line 83, in run
    cls.loop.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 376, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1328, in run
    raise self._exc_info[0](self._exc_info[1]).with_traceback(self._exc_info[2]) TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'doc' and 'pos'
```

lxc lists 15 running

juju status shows:

```
App                    Version      Status       Scale  Charm                  Store       Rev  OS      Notes
ceph-mon               10.2.5       blocked          3  ceph-mon               jujucharms    7  ubuntu  
ceph-osd               10.2.5       active           3  ceph-osd               jujucharms  239  ubuntu  
ceph-radosgw           10.2.5       active           1  ceph-radosgw           jujucharms  245  ubuntu  
glance                 12.0.0       active           1  glance                 jujucharms  254  ubuntu  
keystone               9.2.0        active           1  keystone               jujucharms  262  ubuntu  
lxd                    2.0.8        active           1  lxd                    jujucharms    7  ubuntu  
mysql                  5.6.21-25.8  active           1  percona-cluster        jujucharms  247  ubuntu  
neutron-api            8.3.0        active           1  neutron-api            jujucharms  247  ubuntu  
neutron-gateway        8.3.0        active           1  neutron-gateway        jujucharms  232  ubuntu  
neutron-openvswitch    8.3.0        blocked          1  neutron-openvswitch    jujucharms  238  ubuntu  
nova-cloud-controller  13.1.2       maintenance      1  nova-cloud-controller  jujucharms  292  ubuntu  
nova-compute           13.1.2       active           1  nova-compute           jujucharms  262  ubuntu  
ntp                                 waiting          0  ntp                    jujucharms   17  ubuntu  
openstack-dashboard    9.1.0        active           1  openstack-dashboard    jujucharms  243  ubuntu  exposed
rabbitmq-server        3.5.7        active           1  rabbitmq-server        jujucharms   59  ubuntu  

Unit                      Workload     Agent      Machine  Public address  Ports           Message
ceph-mon/0*               blocked      executing  0        10.177.198.115                  (update-status) Unit not clustered (no quorum)
ceph-mon/1                blocked      executing  1        10.177.198.146                  (update-status) Unit not clustered (no quorum)
ceph-mon/2                blocked      executing  2        10.177.198.175                  (update-status) Unit not clustered (no quorum)
ceph-osd/0                active       executing  3        10.177.198.140                  (update-status) Unit is ready (1 OSD)
ceph-osd/1                active       executing  4        10.177.198.27                   (update-status) Unit is ready (1 OSD)
ceph-osd/2*               active       executing  5        10.177.198.127                  (update-status) Unit is ready (1 OSD)
ceph-radosgw/0*           active       executing  6        10.177.198.135  80/tcp          (update-status) Unit is ready
glance/0*                 active       executing  7        10.177.198.247  9292/tcp        (update-status) Unit is ready
keystone/0*               active       executing  8        10.177.198.184  5000/tcp        Unit is ready
mysql/0*                  active       executing  9        10.177.198.34                   (update-status) Unit is ready
neutron-api/0*            active       executing  10       10.177.198.88   9696/tcp        (update-status) Unit is ready
neutron-gateway/0*        active       executing  11       10.177.198.234                  (update-status) Unit is ready
nova-cloud-controller/0*  maintenance  executing  12       10.177.198.152  8774/tcp        Running nova db migration
nova-compute/0*           active       idle       13       10.177.198.112                  Unit is ready
  lxd/0*                  active       executing           10.177.198.112                  (config-changed) Unit is ready
  neutron-openvswitch/0*  blocked      executing           10.177.198.112                  (start) Missing relations: messaging
openstack-dashboard/0*    active       executing  14       10.177.198.224  80/tcp,443/tcp  (update-status) Unit is ready
rabbitmq-server/0*        active       executing  15       10.177.198.121  5672/tcp        (update-status) Unit is ready

Machine  State    DNS             Inst id         Series  AZ
0        started  10.177.198.115  juju-258996-0   xenial  
1        started  10.177.198.146  juju-258996-1   xenial  
2        started  10.177.198.175  juju-258996-2   xenial  
3        started  10.177.198.140  juju-258996-3   xenial  
4        started  10.177.198.27   juju-258996-4   xenial  
5        started  10.177.198.127  juju-258996-5   xenial  
6        started  10.177.198.135  juju-258996-6   xenial  
7        started  10.177.198.247  juju-258996-7   xenial  
8        started  10.177.198.184  juju-258996-8   xenial  
9        started  10.177.198.34   juju-258996-9   xenial  
10       started  10.177.198.88   juju-258996-10  xenial  
11       started  10.177.198.234  juju-258996-11  xenial  
12       started  10.177.198.152  juju-258996-12  xenial  
13       started  10.177.198.112  juju-258996-13  xenial  
14       started  10.177.198.224  juju-258996-14  xenial  
15       started  10.177.198.121  juju-258996-15  xenial
```

Answer (score 1):

We're transitioning onto snaps for distribution of conjure-up. With that said you'll want to follow the directions at http://conjure-up.io/docs/en/users/#installing-conjure-up

tl;dr

```
sudo apt-get remove conjure-up juju
sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
conjure-up
```